# Chrome harasses me for a keychain password at startup

Tags: password, xfce, chrome

> An application wants to access the keyring 'Default Keyring'

Chrome/Chromium prompts me for a password each time it opens. I don't know why it isn't integrated directly with the OS to unlock with login, but there isn't any obvious way around it.

I read that I need to

```
rm ~/.gnome2/keyrings/default.keyring
```

but I have no such file in my GNOME-less Xfce installation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This problem has a [long history](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/solved-google-chrome-keeps-asking-me-to-login-over-and-over-again/12831/4) and you can fiddle around with `gnome-keyring` if you want, but I found that the [easier](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/keyring-for-chromium-is-pointless/4328/13) solution is to set that prompt's password to blank, such that it won't ask you anymore:

1. `rm ~/.local/share/keyrings/*` (you may want to check/backup these files first, if you're not on a fresh install, e.g., `cp -r ~/.local/share/keyrings ~/keyrings-backup`)
2. Restart Chrome
3. When prompted to create a keyring, continue without entering a password. (Turns out you would have been okay if you did this the first time.)

Comment: Pressing "continue" without entering a password crashed my system the first three times I did it. On the fourth time, I no longer receive prompts, all Gnome extensions were set to "disabled," and Chrome opens four tabs of the Gmail about page every couple of minutes.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but running with --password-store=basic as per jbrock's answer did.

Comment: Keyring without a password is not encrypted. How good is it then?

Comment: Worked great with Opera and Xubuntu 19.04. Thank you! And, I'm not worried about any passwords saved to my browser being unencrypted because I use a third-party password manager and don't save passwords to my browser. Also, I run full dis encryption.

Answer (score 11):

Don't know is this question is still relevant but I found a solution that works for me. I am running Debian Jessie i386. Use the XFCE desktop and gdm3 display manager. What I found was that going into the Applications Menu 
Settings>Session and Startup>Advanced and selecting Launch Gnome Services on Startup cured the problem. Not sure how this would be effected on other distros but it works on Debian Jessie.

Comment: I found the same solution on Xubuntu 17.04 (Zesty).

Comment: Thanks for providing a solution. Unfortunately, this is still relevant. Unfortunately your advice does not work for me debian stretch, with clean install XFCE destkop.

Comment: Helped me with Mint XFCE.

Comment: Doesn't work on Xubuntu 20.04 with XFCE

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what distro you are on, but I would create a script in `~/bin` and call it `chromium` (for Debian) or `chromium-browser` (for Ubuntu). Be sure to adapt the script according to what Chromium is called on your distro:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/chromium-browser --password-store=basic "$@"
```

For Google Chrome, you can create another script in `~/bin` and call it `google-chrome-stable` with the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --password-store=basic "$@"
```

The above scripts will use the argument `--password-store=basic` for every instance when you launch one of the two programs.

From [this source](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches):

--password-store    Specifies which encryption storage backend to use. Possible values are kwallet, kwallet5, gnome, gnome-keyring, gnome-libsecret, basic. Any other value will lead to Chrome detecting the best backend automatically. TODO(crbug.com/571003): Once PasswordStore no longer uses the Keyring or KWallet for storing passwords, rename this flag to stop referencing passwords. Do not rename it sooner, though; developers and testers might rely on it keeping large amounts of testing passwords out of their Keyrings or KWallets.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to comment, but it tells me I cannot because of too few reputation. So sorry for this 'answer'.

The answer from @Wolf to delete the keyrings in `~/.local/share/keyrings/` helped me too. From there on I saw in `Default_keyring.keyring` an explanation for this behaviour.

It seems there is a quirk in the GNOME `libsecret` API and google just adds a dummy entry with libsecret when initializing OSCrypt. See: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=660005 for more details.

Answer (score 0):

All the other answers are much more complicated than necessary. Just purge the package from your system:

`sudo apt purge gnome-keyring`

Comment: Seems like it might be a useful package for something... _if_ it would ever keep synchronized with the login password