# Auto-unlock Chrome default keyring

Tags: debian, chrome, gnome-keyring

Is there any way to auto-unlock the default keyring that pops-up on every start of Chrome, that works on even non-Ubuntu distros? I am using a Debian-based distro. Is there any solution which is popular and universal throughout debian-based distros.

I have seen a solution to this on AskUbuntu StackExchange community, but it works through Ubuntu's own Unity style settings. Another solution [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/324843/chrome-harasses-me-for-a-keychain-password-at-startup) suggests to use blank password instead for the keyring but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: What is your desktop environment ?

Comment: It's Deepin. Comes with its own environment. Not that common. But its based off Debian.

Comment: Someone suggest to start chrome with the command line `google-chrome --password-store=basic` so that it won't ask use the gnome keyring. Anyway I've noticed that the _keyring password_ request only happens with the direct (auto) user login at boot. Every time I log in manually to an account this issue doesn't happens.

Answer (score 0):

Just purge it from your system:

`sudo apt purge gnome-keyring; sudo apt autoremove`